# Switch case ComboBox did not work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, switch-statement

I want to change value in my `TextBox` everytime i change the `ComboBox`, this is my code that is works only for the default `SelectedValue` of `ComboBox`, when i changed the `ComboBox` the `TextBoxes` didn't change.

```
SelectComp_ComboBox.ItemsSource = componentNames;
SelectComp_ComboBox.SelectedValue = componentList[1].componentName;
switch (SelectComp_ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString())
{
    case "02":
        Status_textBlock.Text = componentList[1].componentStatus;
        Width_textBlock.Text = componentList[1].componentWidth;
        Height_textBlock.Text = componentList[1].componentHeight;
        break;
    case "03":
        Status_textBlock.Text = componentList[2].componentStatus;
        Width_textBlock.Text = componentList[2].componentWidth;
        Height_textBlock.Text = componentList[2].componentHeight;
        break;
    case "04":
        Status_textBlock.Text = componentList[3].componentStatus;
        Width_textBlock.Text = componentList[3].componentWidth;
        Height_textBlock.Text = componentList[3].componentHeight;
        break;
}
```

is there any way to make my status, width and height Texboxes changed whenever i change the `ComboBox`?

Comment: Before your code executes the switch case, please put "MessageBox.Show(SelectComp_ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());"
So we can be sure of what data is being passed into the switch case.

My initial thought is that you should be using SelectedIndex instead of SelectedValue since your case statements contain numbers.

Comment: @Brad the combobox itemssource is list of string consist of 02, 03, 04 etc. i put the selected value to be 02 at the start

Comment: Shift your switch-case to SelectionChanged event handler of your ComboBox. Also check for null value of SelectedValue there.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan hm i put the codes on this : `public editA (List<ClassA> componentList) : this() {` so i cant use the list to the SelectionChanged, i tried to add the values of componentList to new List but still can't. any clue?

Comment: @Mirza You have to handle SelectionChanged event of ComboBox anyhow. You can also try using Behaviors.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan ah ok thanks for it, i'll find the solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not using any of wpf advantages here. Do more learning. For quick and dirty answer:

1. set combobox.itemssource with your componentList.
2. Use DataTemplate on combobox xaml to display component name.
3. Subscribe to selected index changed event of combobox
4. Cast selected item of the combobox to your componentList type.
5. Use the above object to set values of your textbox.

But its like using microscope for hammer. Possible but sooooo wrong. Learn

1. MVVM
2. WPF principles like data templates, binding, etc

I am not insulting. But seriously  now your code looks like its from 90th of last century.

Comment: i dont really need MVVM right now, and need to solved it without binding

Comment: You are wrong. If you want to build something useful you need to learn MVVM.